# Car starts when it wants

Tags: toyota, starting, troubleshooting, sensor, diagnostics

I have a 2008 Toyota Corolla and I am having problems with it starting, it seems to only start "when it wants to". I have taken it to 2 Toyota dealers who can't find the problem with it. I have someone tell me that I needed a starter, alternator and a battery, in which I bought all brand new and it still didn't work. I drove it around after the parts were put on and when I was about to go somewhere else later that say it didn't start Again! It started the next day and I went to go get spark plugs which is something else that someone told me to get. The car worked fine throughout the day shutting on and off and starting back up, until later in the day it did the same thing of not starting until waiting after a few minutes. Running out of options, Please help

Comment: Did the vehicle turn over but not start prior to changing the starter?

Comment: When you turn the key and it doesn't start, describe the noises you hear. (if any)

Comment: Yes @resident_heretic

Comment: It sounds like it is Just about to start, but then cuts off. @SteveRacer

Comment: Are you saying the starter motor stops running while you still have the key turned?

Comment: Try a toyota dealer with the diagnostic computer, and ideally the car will misbehave for them.  If its exhibits a "first start in the morning" fault, you may need to leave car with workshop overnight so they can diagnose the cold start with the workshop computer.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you may have a leaking check valve in your fuel line. What can happen is that the fuel leaks past the check valve and back into the tank, which releases the pressure in the fuel rail. When the pressure drops low enough, the remaining fuel in the line vaporizes, and acts like a stopper in the fuel line. The fuel pump can't pump fresh fuel into the line, but the injectors only have fuel vapor to spray into the cylinder. This is why it sounds like it wants to start, but there isn't enough gas to actually run on. After you leave it for a bit, the fuel line cools down and the fuel condenses back into a liquid state and you can start the engine. Find out where you check valve is (could be in the fuel rail or the fuel pump) and replace it.

Answer (score 1):

I had a 2001 Corolla that had a similar problem. It was an evaporative system issue. It was hard to diagnose. I could have been anything from a loose gas cap to purge valves, charcoal canister. In frustration I gave up and traded it in for a new Honda Civic (after I got it started that is). Did you have a check engine light and did the dealer check the code? Sounds like the dealer wanted sell you parts.